# Update Function for all table update in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have written a update function for all tables in php.It works in a very better way .but i think the function is too long . can you please help me to minimize it.Or can you suggest any other easy techniques or  methods.

This is my update function

```
function updatetbl($a,$b,$c)
{
    $a=self::data($a);//calling function inside the function
    $a.="'WHERE ";
    $c=self::data($c);
    $c.="'";
    $SQL="Update  $b set $a $c";
    $result=mysqli_query($SQL);  
    return  $result;
}
```

Where a is data as array ,b is table name,and c is condition.

```
function data($a)
{
    $fields=$a;
    $data="";
    $separator = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
    {
        $data .= $separator . $key . '=\'' . $value; 
        $separator = '\','; 
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: you mean minimize lines counts?

Comment: yes, Or you can suggest any other easy method for updating table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_walk` to loop over the array elements, and `implode` to combine them into a string.

You also should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL-injection.

```
function data($a, $dbcon) {
    return implode(', ', array_map(function($val, $column) use($dbcon) {
        return "`$column` = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $val) . "'";
}, $a);
```

Then you use it like this:

```
function updatetbl($dbcon, $table, $fields, $wheres) {
    $where_string = empty($wheres) ? '' : "WHERE " . self::data($wheres);
    $fields_string = self::data($fields);
    return mysqli_query($dbcon, "UPDATE `$table` SET $fields_string $where_string";
}
```

Note that you were missing the first argument to `mysqli_query()`, the database connection.